# magento 2 - list sales order status all events

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales-order, magento2.4.4

I search for all events used for sales order status.

- sales_order status events
- magento 2.4.4

Comment: Just check the documentation for what you need : https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/events-and-observers/event-list/

Comment: thanks for help, only order status events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this website  link
This page lists three different groups of events occurring in: app and lib folders and global Varien JavaScript Events.

https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento-2.4-list-of-all-dispatched-events

check this some of sales order status events,

**sales_order_place_before**: This event is triggered before a new order is placed. It allows you to modify or validate the order data before it is saved to the database.

**sales_order_place_after**: This event is triggered after a new order is placed. It can be used to perform additional tasks, such as sending order confirmation emails or updating inventory.

**sales_order_save_before**: This event is triggered before an order is saved. It allows you to modify or validate the order data before it is saved to the database.

**sales_order_save_after**: This event is triggered after an order is saved. It can be used to perform additional tasks, such as updating customer data or sending order status updates.

**sales_order_payment_place_start**: This event is triggered when a payment is initiated for an order. It allows you to modify or validate the payment data before it is processed.

**sales_order_payment_place_end**: This event is triggered after a payment is processed for an order. It can be used to perform additional tasks, such as updating order status or sending payment confirmation emails.

Comment: sales order status events

Comment: See edited answer.